# Selenium script issue "0 test class found in package" while running

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to Java and Selenium and not sure what is wrong with my below code

```
    public class SmokeTest{

    static WebDriver driver;
    ArrayList<String> testData = null;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");

    }


    public ArrayList read() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        testData = new ArrayList<>();
  //     File fXmlFile = new File("./blocks-automation/ws/src//Blocks.xml");
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Javaseleniumworld/Blocks.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
//        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("blocks");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                NodeList childEls = eElement.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (int i = 0; i < childEls.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element cElement = (Element) childEls.item(i);
                    testData.add(cElement.getTextContent());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("array" + testData);
        }
        return testData;
    }


    public void main() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        this.read();

        driver.get(testData.get(0));
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

I am not sure how to fix the issue. I tried moving code here and there still not sure how to handle this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I am new to Java and Selenium" ... perhaps spending some time with documentation would help? We cannot teach you Java. You will have to provide a [mcve] in order to get actual help.

Comment: @SiKing I have been spending time going thru documents, there is no need to rephrase my text. I am not asking you to teach me Java, i just needed some direction.

Comment: The problem is that your question contains too little info to be answered. Please post the stacktrace (or exact error message), remove the irrelevant parts of the code (but make sure that the error remains the same), and also add some basic context to the question - do you try to run this as a JUnit/TestNG test (in which case you are missing the `@Test` annotation, etc), or just executing the main method?  What would be the main goal, what is supposed to happen?

Comment: thanks i added @Test and main issue was dependencies and jar files in project structure. I added couple of dependencies and it has started to work. Thanks again for your help!